# Aggregate to multiindex while setting some column names as row names and summarizing sets of columns by them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Long story short, I would like to go from this

```
cat1  cat2  str1_count  str1_a  str1_b  str2_count  str2_a  str2_b

val1  val1         num     num     num         num     num     num
val1  val2         num     num     num         num     num     num                          
val2  val1         num     num     num         num     num     num
val1  val1         num     num     num         num     num     num
val3  val3         num     num     num         num     num     num
val2  val2         num     num     num         num     num     num
```

To this

```
cat1  cat2                  count  avg_a   avg_b  

val1  val1          str1      num    num     num      
                    str2      num    num     num                                  
      val2          str1      num    num     num           
                    str2      num    num     num           
val2  val1          str1      num    num     num           
                    str2      num    num     num           
      val2          str1      num    num     num           
                    str2      num    num     num
val3  val3          str1      num    num     num           
                    str2      num    num     num
```

I'm a bit out of my depth at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Convert columns with no `_` to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first, then split columns for `MultiIndex in columns`, last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last aggregate `mean` and `sum` per all 3 levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['cat1','cat2'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack(0).groupby(level=[0,1,2]).agg({'count':'sum', 'a':'mean', 'b':'mean'})
```

If need changed columns names is possible use named aggregation:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['cat1','cat2'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = (df1.stack(0)
          .groupby(level=[0,1,2])
          .agg(count=('count', 'sum'), avg_a=('a', 'mean'), avg_b=('b', 'mean')))
```

Comment: Yes, this won't work as it will just give me a list of columns as rows per the desired index. And I would like to have only 2 rows with [str1_a,  str1_b] as mean in row str1 in new columns [avg_a, avg_b] and [str2_a,  str2_b] as mean in row str2 in the same columns [avg_a, avg_b]

Comment: @DrDro- I check again and answer was edited, but not sure if it is what need.